# kafka Consumer Reading Previous Records

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

i am facing a problem with my kafka consumer. i have two kafka brokers running with replication factor 2 for the topic. everytime a broker restarts and if i restart my consumer service, it starts to read records which it has already read. e.g. before i restarted the consumer this was the state.

[image]

and consumer was sitting idle not receiving any messages as it has read all of them.
i restart my consumer, and all of a sudden it starts receiving messages which it has processed previously and here is the offset situation now.

[image]

also what is this LOG-END-OFFSET and LAG, looks like these are something to consider here.
note that it only happens when 1 of the broker gets restarted due to kubernetes shifting it to another node.

this is the topic configuration

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info you posted, a couple of things that immediately come to mind:

- The first screenshot shows a lag of 182, which means the consumer either was not running, or it has some weird configuration that made it stop consuming.  Was it possible one of the brokers was down when the consumer stopped consuming?
- On restart, the consumer finally consumed all the remaining messages, because it now shows lag of 0.  This is correct, expected Kafka behavior.
- Make sure that the consumer group name is not changing between restarts.  Some clients default to "randomized" customer group names, which works as long as the consumer is not restarted.

Comment: the consumer was live when a broker restarted, and it did read all the messages as soon as the broker was up, problem is. if i restart my consumer it'll re-read the messages